# How can I convert a Windows OsString to a CString?

Tags: rust, ffi

I have an `std::ffi::OsString` on Windows, but I need to pass a `std::ffi::CString` to an FFI function. Is there any way to convert the `OsString` into the `CString`?

I know that on Windows, `OsString` is backed by a WTF-8-encoded buffer. Essentially all that needs to happen is to append an ASCII `nul` character and create a CString from it. Is there a good way to do that? If not, is is possible to access that buffer directly?

Here is some example code:

```rust
extern "system" fn some_ffi(s: *mut c_char);

fn my_func(os_string: &OsString) {
    let c_string: CString = // ???

    some_ffi(c_string.as_raw())
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On Unix-like systems, you can obtain the raw bytes of an `OsStr` or `OsString` as a `&[u8]` via [`std::os::unix::ffi::OsStrExt::as_bytes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/unix/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.as_bytes). You can pass that slice directly to [`CString::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.CString.html#method.new).

On Windows, you *cannot* obtain the raw bytes of an `OsStr` or `OsString`. The WTF-8 encoding is considered a private implementation detail. The only guarantee is that if the string contains valid Unicode, then it can be converted to a `str` or `String` in constant time, using [`OsStr::to_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_str) or [`OsString::into_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.into_string). You can also convert the string back to potentially ill-formed UTF-16 with [`std::os::windows::ffi::OsStrExt::encode_wide`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/os/windows/ffi/trait.OsStrExt.html#tymethod.encode_wide).

The motivation for not giving direct access to the raw bytes is that almost no library expects strings encoded as WTF-8. In fact, some libraries might not even expect UTF-8! (They might instead expect strings encoded in the [current "ANSI" code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getacp).) If it turns out that the library doesn't expect UTF-8 strings, you should instead convert the potentially ill-formed UTF-16 string to the expected encoding using [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-ca/windows/desktop/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte).